# Java SDK 11.0 or above is required when using .NET 6 or higher

Tags: java, .net, installation, java-11, maui

I've installed .NET 6 (version *6.0.100-rc.1.21458.32*) and Visual Studio 2020 Preview (although it might be not a prerequisite).

I am trying to debug a hello-world application but I am getting a **build error regarding  Java**.

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\31.0.100-rc.1.12\targets\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Tooling.targets(20,5): error XA0031: 
Java SDK 11.0 or above is required when using .NET 6 or higher.
```

I've installed Java 17 setting `Path` as well as pointing to the Java Development Kit Location in Visual Studio settings (tools->options->Xamarin->Android Settings). Because that didn't work I've set the JDK location to Microsoft's openjdk, but it still doesn't work.

[image]

What's wrong here?

Comment: The screenshot shows "1.8.0.25". That's not 17. The error says you need 11 or newer, 1.8 is too old.

Comment: I just get this  "warning XA0033: Failed to get the Java SDK version because the returned value does not appear" and the it fails to deploy

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Installing Microsoft's [OpenJDK 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/openjdk/download) did the job for me.

> *You may notice that Visual Studio installs a version of Microsoft*
> *OpenJDK, **however, you need to install the Microsoft OpenJDK 11***

Comment: Just as an FYI, this requirement is specified in the following article.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/installation

Answer (score 21):

For those who have the same problem in **Jetbrains Rider** :

1. **Install OpenJDK 11** (**Microsoft's OpenJDK 11** seems to be better) as mentioned by @themelis
2. Press **Ctrl + Shift + A** and search **MSBuild global properties** or go to **File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Toolset and Build**
3. **Edit** the **MSBuild global properties** and **add** the following property:

`Name: JavaSdkDirectory
Value: {OpenJDK installation directory} (mine is C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot)`

[image]

4. **Save** and **Enjoy**!

Answer (score 9):

When I installed VS2022 preview 4, my configuration became `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.10.9-hotspot`

This can be fixed for you if you run the `maui-check` command (if you installed that component during visual studio installation).

If you don't have the `maui-check` tool, you can get it by running the `dotnet tool install -g Redth.Net.Maui.Check` command

Maybe you skipped a step during installation and that's why you get the error.

Comment: I have installed maui-check. It executes without printing something on the console, so I assume everything is ok.

Comment: That is not correct. It should print that everything is Ok. Try opening a powershell terminal with admin rights (just to make sure) and run the command

Comment: This is [official repository](https://github.com/Redth/dotnet-maui-check) of the tool. And this is an [example gif of the output](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/271950/112761851-29f53180-8fcb-11eb-92be-c843c794b2af.gif) (you don't have to use the --dev parameter)

Comment: You were right about `maui-check`. Although the output points to a problem regarding .NET 5. `The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '5.0.0' (x64) was not found.` That can't be it. I had .NET 5 and I assume it got upgraded after .NET 6 installation.

Comment: Net5 is not required for MAUI development. If you follow [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/installation), it should contain all that you need. If you want to make sure, uninstall any VS2022 preview or .Net6 preview before installing Visual Studio 2022 preview 4

Comment: Well that's what I was trying to avoid, thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 7):

## Visual Studio for Mac

Here's how I got it working on macOS with Visual Studio for Mac.

### Install Microsoft Open JDK

On macOS, [install the Microsoft Open JDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/java/openjdk/install#install-on-macos?WT.mc_id=mobile-0000-bramin) using HomeBrew:

```sh
brew install --cask microsoft-openjdk
```

### Configure Visual Studio for Mac

1. In Visual Studio for Mac, select **Visual Studio** -> **Preferences**.
2. In the **Preferences** window, navigate to **SDK Locations** -> **Android** -> **Locations**.
3. In the **Java SDK (JDK) Location:** text box, enter the following:

```sh
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

4. Click **OK**

[image]

Comment: I followed the directions above, but it generated the following:
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home` and `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/microsoft-17.jdk/Contents/Home`.  Neither one removed the original error.

Comment: @JamesJordanTaylor You can check my answer for actual resolution.

Comment: Downloading the Microsoft OpenJDK v11 worked for me. I had the same issue as @JamesJordanTaylor mentions above

Answer (score 5):

You may start getting this error on Azure DevOps build pipelines for MAUI/Xamarin using the new MSBuild 17.8.3 that started rolling out over the last couple of days (20 Nov 2023). Same with Github Actions.

Solution detailed here: [MAUI / Xamarin build failing with "Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Tooling.targets(20,5): error XA0031: Java SDK 11.0 or above is required when using .NET 6"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77519046/maui-build-failing-with-microsoft-android-sdk-tooling-targets20-5-error-xa00/77519051#77519051)

Comment: how to do the same in GitHubActions???

Comment: hi @knocte, 

I had the same problem. you can just add this action before publishing.


```
- name: Setup Java JDK
  uses: actions/setup-java@v3.13.0
  with:
    distribution: 'microsoft'
    java-version: '17'
```

Answer (score 0):

For those here who use github actions:

```
  - name: Install .NET MAUI
    shell: pwsh
    run: |
      dotnet workload install maui --source https://aka.ms/dotnet6/nuget/index.json --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
      dotnet workload install android maui wasm-tools --source https://aka.ms/dotnet6/nuget/index.json --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
      
  - uses: actions/setup-java@v2
    with:
      distribution: 'microsoft'
      java-version: '11'
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up for the answer from @Mohammad-R: in Rider 2023.3 for Windows I fixed it by manually setting Java Development Kit Location in Andriod settings. Didn't work with the latest JDK 21, had to install JDK 17 to make a build. No changes to MSBuild global properties were required

[settings tree screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0Lut.png)