# Java SDK 11.0 or above is required when using $(TargetFrameworkVersion) v12.0

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-play-console

While Creating APK At Android API LEvel 31 i Got Above Error.I updated jdk version from 8.0 to 19.0 still got Above error. using -Visual 2019. Don't Know What To Do.Please Provide Some Help.

How Do I Solve This Problem.Please Guide i am not able to publish app on playstore.

Comment: Considering you use VS2019, you can uninstall it and install latest version of Visual Studio to see if it works properly.

Comment: Yes, I am using Visual studio 2019 ,I install latest version of visual studio 2022m,In latest Visual studio ,Xamarin form Folder are not loaded. only android and ios are visible and loaded. so i am not able to understand why xamarin forms folder are not get Load.

Comment: According to the situation you described, you can perform the Repair operation on VS. For more information about Repair, you can check [Repair Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error, first you need to update your Java JDK to version 11.0 or above.
After updating SDK make sure you set the right path under Java JDK location under Visual studio.

Click Tools > Options…
Within the left-hand tree of the Options dialog box, select Xamarin > Android Settings:

[image]

Comment: I updated Java SDK to version from 8.0 to 19 still got same error.

Comment: @INDOSOFTCONSULTANTS Instead of Java SDK, you should install the [Microsoft OpenJDK 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/openjdk/download).

Comment: Yeah I tried ,but still getting same error.

Comment: @INDOSOFTCONSULTANTS You can run `the dotnet tool install -g Redth.Net.Maui.Check ` command to fix it. In addition, you can check [Java SDK 11.0 or above is required when using .NET 6 or higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69259265/java-sdk-11-0-or-above-is-required-when-using-net-6-or-higher).